# Probability Question, can you confirm my thoughts

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out this probability question for a program I am writing. I have described an example scenario below:

```
There are 7 marbles of different color in a bag. 
6 different colors were drawn in the 25 total draws.
```

The first part:

To find the percent of the time a new marble was chosen, you would divide the number of different color marbles drawn (6) by the number of total draws (25), correct? So a new marble was drawn 6/25 % of the time?

(@Kemp: By 'new' marble, I mean a marble that has not yet been drawn.)

The second part:

```
There were 5 repeated marbles.
```

For example:

```
6 Pink
4 Purple
3 Orange
6 Black
5 Blue
1 Red
0 Green
```

My question is: What is the percent chance that the next marble will have been already drawn?

Would you just do the number of repeated marbles (5) divided by the number of different colors drawn (6)? Would there be a 5/6 % chance to draw an already drawn marble?

Comment: What do you mean by "a **new** marble was drawn *such-n-such* percent of the time?"  What are you looking to calculate?

Comment: Yes, the first part is 6/25.  A probability is always a number between 0 and 1.  If you want to express as a percent ("per-hundred") you multiply by 100.

Comment: `"By 'new' marble, I mean a marble that has not yet been drawn."` -- **when** is "not yet"?

Comment: Anyway, every time you pick, if there are $x$ total marbles in the bag, and $y$ of them satisfy a certain property $P$, then the probability that you pick a marble that satisfies property $P$ is $y/x$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp : I think his first part means the fraction of picks (out of 25) that produced a color that was not seen on any of the previous picks.  So, 6/25.  So you have binary random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{25}$, and $X_i=1$ if and only if the color observed on pick $i$ was not observed on any picks $\{1, ..., i-1\}$.  So the empirical average in his example is $(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{25})/25 = 6/25$.